# Typescript autocompletion not working fine in VS Code (NestJS)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs

Below code is generated from `nest g res users`.

When adding `BadRequestException` in VS Code, refactoring feature (`Ctrl + .`) works fine but autocompletion does not. It does not autocomplete the name and needs to use `Ctrl + .` to add import statement.

[VS Code refactoring feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQnQy.png)

[VSCode autocompletion feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAtSu.png)

Same autocompletion feature works fine in PyCharm 2023.1.2. It autocompletes the name and adds import statement.

[PyCharm autocompletion feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd53z.png)

I think my VSCode recognizes node_modules path correctly, because refactoring feature works fine. But I have no idea why the autocompletion feature does not work. :(

I've enabled below features in my VS Code.

- built-in "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features"
- plugin "npm Intellisense".
- plugin "IntelliCode".

Any recommendations for better JS/TS autocompletion in VS Code?

---

Currently, I'm using `"typescript.suggest.enabled": true` in VS Code.

And here is my `npm list`.

- `@nestjs/cli@9.5.0`
- `@nestjs/common@9.4.3`
- `@nestjs/core@9.4.3`
- `@nestjs/mapped-types@2.0.0`
- `@nestjs/platform-express@9.4.3`
- `@nestjs/schematics@9.2.0`
- `@nestjs/testing@9.4.3`
- `@types/express@4.17.17`
- `@types/jest@29.5.1`
- `@types/node@18.16.12`
- `@types/supertest@2.0.12`
- `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.60.0`
- `@typescript-eslint/parser@5.60.0`
- `eslint-config-prettier@8.8.0`
- `eslint-plugin-prettier@4.2.1`
- `eslint@8.43.0`
- `jest@29.5.0`
- `prettier@2.8.8`
- `reflect-metadata@0.1.13`
- `rxjs@7.8.1`
- `source-map-support@0.5.21`
- `supertest@6.3.3`
- `ts-jest@29.1.0`
- `ts-loader@9.4.3`
- `ts-node@10.9.1`
- `tsconfig-paths@4.2.0`
- `typescript@5.1.3`

---

### Reproducing the problem

#### System information

- Windows 11 Home
- Visual Studio Code 1.79.2
- npm 9.5.1

#### Global packages installed

- @nestjs/cli@9.5.0
- eslint@8.43.0
- typescript@5.1.3

#### Commands

```
// Select npm for package manager
> nest new project
> cd project

// Select REST API and generate CRUD entry points
> nest g res users
> code .
```

In file `project/src/users/users.controller.ts`:

```js
...

@Get(':id')
findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
  // Here is the problem, cannot find `BadRequestException`
  if (+id > 1) {
    throw new BadReq<autocomplete>
  }
  return this.usersService.findOne(+id);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the cause of the problem, I tried some ways.

First I tried to reproduce the problem on MacOS Ventura, but the problem doesn't happen.

Next, I tried this on a new Windows instance, but it also couldn't reproduce the problem.

So I came back to my development environment and removed VS Code completely and reinstalled it. This doesn't help at all.

Finally, I removed and reinstalled npm. After that the problem disappeared.

**I couldn't figure out what is the cause of the problem.
But for some cases, reinstalling npm could fix your autocomplete problem on VS Code.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).